# Why does not BarLegend accept user-defined color function?

Tags: legending

I encountered a really strange problem with `BarLegend`.
Say you have a user-defined color function:

```
cf[z_]:=RGBColor[RandomReal[z, 3]]
```

When you want to use it in `BarLegend` as below:

```
BarLegend[{cf, {1, 10}}]
```

Mathematica will generate a blank bar shown as below:
[image]

However, after I change the function head in `BarLegend` to a pure function:

```
BarLegend[{cf[#]&, {1, 10}}]
```

Mathematica can give desired result.

I cannot figure out why Mathematica doesn't accept user-defined color function.
Could anyone please give a clue?

Comment: Does `cf = Function[z, RGBColor[RandomReal[z, 3]]]` work better?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you look into the source code

```
ClearAttributes[BarLegend, ReadProtected]
?? BarLegend
```

And into nested functions (`` BarLegend,Charting`iBarLegend `` $\to$ `` Legending`LegendDump`iColorBandLegend `` $\to$ `` Legending`LegendDump`parseColorBand ``) you can find the following code

```
Switch[Legending`LegendDump`colorfunction,
_String, ColorData[Legending`LegendDump`colorfunction]/@Legending`LegendDump`values,
_ColorDataFunction, Legending`LegendDump`colorfunction/@Legending`LegendDump`values,
_List, Switch[Legending`LegendDump`fn, Legending`ColorBandLegend,With[{Legending`LegendDump`list=Legending`LegendDump`colorfunction},Blend[Legending`LegendDump`list,#1]&]/@Legending`LegendDump`values,
BarLegend|_, Legending`LegendDump`iter=Max[Length[Legending`LegendDump`colorfunction]-Length[Legending`LegendDump`values],0];Do[Legending`LegendDump`colorfunction=Reverse[Charting`padList[Legending`LegendDump`colorfunction,Length[Legending`LegendDump`colorfunction]-1]],{Legending`LegendDump`iter}];If[OddQ[Legending`LegendDump`iter],Reverse[Legending`LegendDump`colorfunction],Legending`LegendDump`colorfunction]],
Hue|GrayLevel, (Legending`LegendDump`colorfunction[#1]&)/@Legending`LegendDump`values,
_Function, Legending`LegendDump`colorfunction/@Legending`LegendDump`values,
_, Return[{}]]
```

It shows that the function must have the `Function` header.

Comment: So could you provide a working example please?

Answer (score 0):

With this response I tried:

```
maxmin = {10, 20};
BarLegend[{Function[x, Hue[0.8 Rescale[x, maxmin]]], maxmin}]
```

which worked nicely to truncate the Hue function to remove the red at the top